# Change file/path extension

Tags: c++

Using VC++, how can I remove the extension from the following file path and change it to a new extension(using strings):

```
CString path(_T(m_DirTree.GetCurrentDir()));             // copy file path to variable 'path' of type CString

//Add code here....
```

The path to the file in question is L:\PowerStar 5 Demo II\Programs\Demo\Programs\33100.PRG and I would like to change the file extension to 33100.CRC. Is there some way I could use _splitpath to change the file extension to .CRC? This path is one of many which can be selected via a directory tree that is passed to variable path and I am just using this particular path as an example. So I cannot alter it as below:

```
CString path(_T("L:\PowerStar 5 Demo II\Programs\Demo\Programs\33100.CRC"));
```

Is it possible to concatenate the strings so I can open without getting an exception?

```
char drive[_MAX_DRIVE]; 
char dir[_MAX_DIR]; 
char fname[_MAX_FNAME]; 
char ext[_MAX_EXT];


// Split path to isolate file extension(.prg) for if statement 

_splitpath(m_DirTree.GetCurrentDir(), drive, dir, fname, ext);

CString crcFile; 

crcFile = strcat(fname,".CRC");  // concatenate chars to point to .CRC file of same name


FILE *cr = fopen(fname, "r");  // Handle to the file in question
```

The above code throws an unhandled exception.

Comment: If you use backslashes in string literals then you need to escape them. Use `"\\"`. If you don't want to think about it, use forward-slashes `"/"` which Windows have been able to handle almost from day one.

Comment: Find the last `.` and remove after it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the Shell API function [PathRenameExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773749.aspx). Or if you want the buffer management handled for you [CPathT::RenameExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf15zaf9.aspx), for example:

```
CPath path(_T("L:\\PowerStar 5 Demo II\\Programs\\Demo\\Programs\\33100.PRG"));
path.RenameExtension(_T(".CRC"));
CString modifiedPath = path;
```

Answer (score 2):

CString has 2 methods, which might help you.
ReverseFind() and Left()

```
CString filenameWithoutExtension = path.Left(path.ReverseFind(_T('.')));
```

Then you can add your new file extension (e.g. ".exe") at the end of the new string.

```
path = filenameWithoutExtension + _T(".exe");
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this advice works perfectly since I'm not using std::string

Comment: Do not forget to check, if "path.ReverseFind(_T('.')" does find a dot in the filename first. If there is no '.', path.ReverseFind(_T('.') will return -1.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up..I'll throw in a few conditions

Comment: @Mr.Yellow I don't recommend doing this.   There are path manipulation functions that already exist in Windows, and you should be using those instead of writing your own code.  Writing your own may look trivial, but as you can see for yourself, you have corner cases you didn't consider.  Let the shlwapi.lib  `Path` functions do this work.