# How to avoid file corruption on abnormal shutdown?

Tags: windows

I am posting this question as exact answer is not found anywhere.

**Problem** : In one of the application I am working, we need to consider the power outages / abnormal shutdowns also in coding. The application modify / create some files while running(Let us assume a simple .txt files).

It is observed that when power failure occurs while application is running, all the created / modified files are corrupted. To be precise, we can see the file's meta data but if we open the files, all contents are gone and file is empty. When we open the file in Notepad++, the file is filled with NULL.

It is identified that due to some OS optimization mechanisms all file contents are written to disk later even though technically we complete the write operation before.

**Technical Details :** The application is on c++. We used normal CStdioFile call for FILE IO operations.

**Question** : Are there any coding practices to avoid these file corruptions?

Comment: Nothing to do with C++.

Answer (score 1):

The only application level solution (without getting into clever file systems etc) is to keep a copy of old "unchanged" files so that you can restore to a "safe" state.

if someone pulls the plug in the middle of a write then the file you were writing to is almost certainly corrupt but if you were working on a copy and still have the original then you can forget the corrupt copy and "step back" to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

Write new version to another file in the destination folder. I usually use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29282320/126995) to replace extension with “.tmp” but in modern C++ there’s a built-in crossplatform way too, [replace_extension](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/path/replace_extension).

When you’re done, flush and close the file. This will cause OS to write changes to HDD. Then use e.g. [MoveFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx) with MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING flag to replace your destination file with the newly written temporary file. The replace operation is [almost always](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/449bb49d-8acc-48dc-a46f-0760ceddbfc3/movefileexmovefilereplaceexisting-ntfs-same-volume-atomic?forum=windowssdk) atomic.